# How to make tkinter entry a variable in another python script

Tags: python, tkinter, python-os

I Have created 2 scripts.

1.`rec.py` uses `tkinter` to enter user input

2.`classify.py` uses input from `rec.py` to perform transformations

What I want to achieve:

1. call user input from `rec.py` and make it a variable in `classify.py`
2. use variable to perform tranformations in `classify.py`
3. print output of `classify.py`

What i did:

`rec.py`:

```
def click(text_user_example):
    text_user = text_user_example
    os.system("classify.py")

#create a text entry box
text_user = Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
text_user.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

#add a submit button
Button(window, text="SUBMIT", width=6, command = lambda: 
click(text_user)).grid(row=3, column=0,  sticky=W)
```

`classify.py`:

```
from rec import text_user #this is the only variable i want from "rec.py"
--other tranformations using text_user
print(text_user)
```

Unfortunately, every time i run `classify.py` the `tkinter` interface pops up even after i have submitted my input(the interface should not pop up after text-user has been entered).

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: *"What am i doing wrong?"*: Your `rec.py` is **not** a `module`. Read [what-does-if-name-main-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: `classify.py` uses `rec.py` and `rec.py` calls `classify.py` -> infinite loop.